# Invoke the "Run" command

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to invoke the "Run" dialogue box that is often on the Start Menu - I did some research and have only managed to find one way of accessing it (using "Windows Key" + R).

So I assume simulating key strokes e.g.:

```
SendKeys.Send("{TEST}")
```

would do the job? Although how can you simulate the "Windows" key on the keyboard?

I am sure there is an easier way of doing this - without using sendkeys - anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What you are trying to do with "Run" Dialog? You can use process.start to start any process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PInvoke to invoke Run dialog.

```
[Flags()]
public enum RunFileDialogFlags : uint
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Don't use any of the flags (only works alone)
    /// </summary>
    None = 0x0000,    

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the browse button
    /// </summary>
    NoBrowse = 0x0001,

    /// <summary>
    /// No default item selected
    /// </summary>
    NoDefault = 0x0002,

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the working directory from the file name
    /// </summary>
    CalcDirectory = 0x0004,

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the edit box label
    /// </summary>
    NoLabel = 0x0008,

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the separate memory space checkbox (Windows NT only)
    /// </summary>
    NoSeperateMemory = 0x0020
}
```

we need to Import the DLL using the DllImport attribute.

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "#61", SetLastError = true)]

static extern bool SHRunFileDialog(IntPtr hwndOwner, 
                                   IntPtr hIcon, 
                                   string lpszPath,
                                   string lpszDialogTitle, 
                                   string lpszDialogTextBody, 
                                   RunFileDialogFlags uflags);
```

**Implementation:**

```
private void ShowRunDialog(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SHRunFileDialog(IntPtr.Zero, 
                    IntPtr.Zero, 
                    "c:\\",
                    "Run Dialog using PInvoke",
                    "Type the name of a program, folder or internet address 
            and Windows will open that for you.",
                    RunFileDialogFlags.CalcDirectory);
```

}

Comment: Note that the `SHRunFileDialog` function is undocumented and may change or stop working at any time. Make sure your customers understand this.